# How to setup gitconfig for default remote name?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I want to set up my git (TortoiseGIT) using the global gitconfig file such that the default remote name when I clone a repository is not "origin" but some other text defines by me (e.g. "foo").

Is this possible? Which directives are the ones?

Thanks

Edit: The intention of that is, that I create several smaller repositories for different, independent tasks (documentation!) and I am tired of every time modifying the name of the remote since it is available using shares to other users. So the name of the remote should be my machine's name to avoid confusing the other git versions. I know this is not best practice but that's life :(.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no global config option. You will have to use `git clone --origin foo <source>` to change the name of the "origin" repository when you clone it:

```
--origin <name>, -o <name>  
   Instead of using the remote name origin to keep track of the upstream
   repository, use <name>.
```

Comment: This does change the name the time I clone the repositry. I want to be able to specify the name once and from then on, ALL clone actions should use that name.

Comment: You can't, so I'm offering the next-best thing.

Comment: Sounds like a patch is in order.

Comment: Is this still true as of 2015? I'm secretly hoping they've added a new config option in the last four years...

Comment: @yochannah Why? How often are you cloning repositories that you need to worry? Why would you *want* to change the name of the original remote?

Comment: @meagar because I'm working on an open source project, and the thought of inadvertently cloning and pushing to the 'master' remote before I'm ready gives me the heebie-jeebies. Explicit naming makes this easier. Compare `yochannah/awesomeOSSProject` and `awesomeOSSProject/awesomeOSSProject` vs the less clear `origin/awesomeOSSProject` and `upstream/awesomeOSSProject`. It's a lot easier to tell which is which, now, and it saves me time when I clone a lot of sub-projects if I don't have to rename the remotes as often.

Comment: http://coala.io recommends newbies use `upstream`, 'cause there are too many 'helpful' scripts on the 'net which assume `origin` is the fork, or the forked, and they shoot themselves in the foot, and they blame the tool.  If they dont have an origin, most destructive scripts fail early.

Comment: You can add an alias for this like: `git config --global alias.fooclone ’clone --origin foo’`. Then use it like `git fooclone <repo>`.

Comment: @meagar, starting with Git 2.30.0 (2020-12-27) this is no longer true. Now there is `clone.defaultRemoteName`, see my answer for more details. But it took them long to have it added...

Answer (score 6):

Git 2.30.0 (2020-12-27) introduced [`clone.defaultRemoteName`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.30.0#Documentation/git-config.txt-clonedefaultRemoteName) configuration value that is described the following:

> The name of the remote to create when cloning a repository. Defaults to `origin`, and can be overridden by passing the `--origin` command-line option to [git-clone[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

while at the same time the [`--origin` command-line option of `git-clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone/2.30.0#Documentation/git-clone.txt--oltnamegt) changed its description to:

> Instead of using the remote name `origin` to keep track of the upstream repository, use `<name>`. Overrides `clone.defaultRemoteName` from the config.

To get the value use

```
git config --get clone.defaultRemoteName
```

The default `origin` seems to be added by a hardcode in the source code since if you don't have this configuration value you get an error (missing key). However, if you are using at least Git 2.18.0 (2018-06-21) then there is a [`--default` command-line option to `git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.18.0#Documentation/git-config.txt---defaultltvaluegt), simplifying to:

```
git config --default origin --get clone.defaultRemoteName
```

How to set the value depends on the scope you want to set it in but it is no different than any other configuration value, so there should be plenty of help on the topic (of setting Git configuration values).

Comment: Interestingly, this means that starting from Git 2.30.0 (2020-12-27) any scripting that is supposed to be generic and flexible, can no longer assume that after `git clone` the remote is named `origin`. Now it must either enforce it with the `--origin` argument or thereafter use `"$(git remote)"` to query the remote name. (Well, it could also use `git config` to get `defaultRemoteName` but it doesn't seem to have advantages over `git remote` while it is prone to global configuration changes in the same time.)

Comment: `git config --get clone.defaultRemoteName` doesn't work with Git 2.38.4 - it prints nothing and returns exit code 1. `git config --default origin --get clone.defaultRemoteName` still works, for the obvious reason. How would I get the actual default of a configuration value?

Comment: @l0b0, not that I wrote "if you don't have this configuration value you get an error (missing key)". The --default is the only way around it. But it does mean you have to repeat the "origin" and if Git as some point changes their hardcoded value you will then be wrong. Sadly, I don't know any _practical_ way to get the name. (For impractical: make a new repo and see how the remote is named.)